# Does AWS IAM user login integration can be done with custom application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

For my custom application, i wanted to have user login handled by AWS, basically i wanted the IAM user login functionality and call back to application on successful login. Like the integrations with "Sign in with Google".

I do understand the AWS Cognito does this, but i wanted to have MFA with this user using a hardware key which is not supported by  Cognito as my understanding.

Hardware key MFA is possible with IAM users, so  if i can create a app which allows the IAM user to login on AWS and redirect back to my app with a callback or token then it will be good, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

An IAM user/role is meant to log into AWS Management Console and when using the AWS SDK when creating Service clients. You use the credentials of an IAM user.

If you are not familiar with using an IAM user with the SDK, see this topic:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

What you are describing is a use case for Cognito and users defined within user pools. For example, you can protect your web apps by requiring a user to login with a user defined in a user pool using a login form such as:

[image]